# $\text{aff }C$ is the smallest affine set containing $C$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, and $C \subseteq D$ where $D$ is affine.

Show that $\text{aff }C \subseteq D$

**What I tried**:

Take $y \in \text{aff }C$. Then $y = \sum_{i=1}^{k}t_ix_i$ where $x_i \in C$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k}t_i = 1$.

We wish to show that $y \in D$. Once we show that, we're done.

Now, since $C \subseteq D$, then $x_i \in D$ as well. So $y = \sum_{i=1}^{k}t_ix_i$ is an affine combination of elements in $D$ too.

That's all well and good, but I want to reach the form $y = \lambda w_1 + (1-\lambda) w_2$ where $w_1, w_2 \in D$. Then I would know that $y \in D$, because $D$ is affine.

Write $t_2 = 1-t_1 - t_3 -\dots -t_k$.

Then $y = t_1x_1 + (1-t_1 - t_3 - \dots -t_k)x_2 + t_3x_3+\dots t_kx_k = \\t_1x_1+(1-t_1)x_2+(-t_3-t_4-\dots -t_k)x_2+t_3x_3+\dots t_kx_k$

Since $D$ is affine, $t_1x_1 + (1-t_1)x_2 \in D$

I'm unsure how to continue now or if this is even the right direction

I realize this has been asked before, but the answer there only works if $C$ is known to be a linear subspace. We don't know that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if we choose an element $x_0 \in C$ and define
$$
\hat C = \{x - x_0 : x \in C\}; \quad \hat D = \{x - x_0 : x \in D\},
$$
then it suffices to apply the result on linear subspaces to $\hat C \subseteq \hat D$.

That being said, to complete your proof it suffices to apply the following:

> **Claim:** If $D$ is affine, then any affine combination of $\sum_{i=1}^k t_i x_i$ of elements in $D$ will also be an element of $D$.

**Proof:** Proceed inductively.  Suppose that we know that any affine combination of $n \geq 2$ elements is necessarily an element of $D$.  Now, consider $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} t_i x_i$.  It cannot be the case that $t_i = 1$ for all $i$, so without loss of generality suppose that $t_{n+1} \neq 1$. We have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} t_i x_i = 
\sum_{i=1}^{n} t_i x_i + t_{n+1}x_{n+1} = 
(1-t_{n+1})\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{t_i}{1 - t_{n+1}} x_i\right) + t_{n+1}x_{n+1}
$$
So that $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} t_i x_i$ is an affine combination of two elements of $D$ and is therefore in $D$.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.